# CSS - Classes not applying to email template

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, css

I am sending a email using form values. I created email template using so many css classes. When I sent email, found that no one class is applied in email template.

I search for solution of this issue but not found satisfactory answer. Is any one know, how to apply css classes for email template.

I am using CodeIgniter framework and creating email in a action "sendemail". Here is sample code.

```
<style>
 .head{
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
 }
</style>

<div class='head'>
 Hello World !
</div>
```

Please let me know if there is any solution.

Comment: So, in the email that was received, there was no CSS?  If that is the problem, you should know that emails always work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In email templates css classes will not affect you have write inline style to html tags like

```
<div style='border: 2px solid black;padding:5px;'>Hello World !</div>
```

Comment: It's really annoying.